# How to extract a single word from the output of a Linux command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

`$ lsusb --verbose | grep "THRSL_C_C_V"`

results in:
  `iManufacturer           1 THRSL_C_C_V3.07`

I want to extract the word `THRSL_C_C_V3.07` only.

I tried `lsusb --verbose | grep -w "THRSL_C_C_V"`. Didn't show anything.

Comment: Use: `lsusb --verbose | awk '/THRSL_C_C_V/{print $3}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `awk` instead of `grep`:

```
lsusb --verbose | awk '/THRSL_C_C_V/{print $3}'
```

This `awk` command searches a line that has text `THRSL_C_C_V` in it and by using `print $3` we make sure to print 3rd column of matched line.

**Alternatively** you can use `grep -o` like this:

```
echo 'iManufacturer        1 THRSL_C_C_V3.07' |
grep -oE 'THRSL_C_C_V[^[:blank:]]*'
```

```
THRSL_C_C_V3.07
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
lsusb --verbose | grep -o "THRSL_C_C_V3\.07"
```

The `-o` options results in only matching text, the backlash escapes the dot allowing an exact match of the requested text.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:-

```
$ lsusb --verbose | grep "THRSL_C_C_V" |  awk '{print $NF}'
```

or

```
$ lsusb --verbose | awk '/THRSL_C_C_V/{print $NF}'
```

Here, $NF will be used for the last element of output

Comment: No need to use `grep + awk`. `awk` alone can do the job